# Using and MP4 as a div background and fill the space as the window is resized

Tags: html, canvas, mp4

I have tried using the  tag but when the window is resize I need the video to fill the space as the window is resized.  At the largest scale it fills the space and as is shrinks it starts to add a lot of white space at the top and bottom.

**HTML**

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="images/user_item.mp4" class="w-100" style="">
    <source src="images/user_item.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**CSS**

```
video { 
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
```

Is it possible to play the video in a canvas and resize the canvas and have it fill the entire space provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a canvas, just use CSS. In particular here you want the [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property.

By default for video it's set to `contains`, meaning it will set the size of the media to the smallest side and add borders to the largest, keeping the aspect-ratio of the media.

From your description it's quite unclear if you want the `cover` which keeps aspect-ratio but cuts the media,

```css
video { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm" autoplay loop muted></video>
```

or `fill`, which just stretches/shrinkes the media.

```css
video { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm" autoplay loop muted></video>
```

And for future readers, note that this CSS property can also be set to <canvas>.

Comment: You are amazing, thank you. I have never heard of Object fit.